# Create PDF with HTML2PDF and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, html2pdf

I have problem with create PDF and MySQL using HTML2PDF Librairy.
I would like to display an image and does not show.
Does anybody know how to do that?

For example: I have code below:

### bookmark.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
    table.page_header {width: 100%; border: none; background-color: #DDDDFF; border-bottom: solid 1mm #AAAADD; padding: 2mm }
    table.page_footer {width: 100%; border: none; background-color: #DDDDFF; border-top: solid 1mm #AAAADD; padding: 2mm}
    h1 {color: #000033}
    h2 {color: #000055}
    h3 {color: #000077}

    div.niveau
    {
        padding-left: 5mm;
    }
-->
</style>
<page backtop="14mm" backbottom="14mm" backleft="10mm" backright="10mm" style="font-size: 12pt">
    <page_header>
        <table class="page_header">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100%; text-align: left">
                    <img src=showimage.php alt="image" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </page_header>
    <page_footer>
        <table class="page_footer">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100%; text-align: right">
                    page [[page_cu]]/[[page_nb]]
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </page_footer>
</page>
<?php
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../html2pdf.class.php');
    try
    {
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', 0);
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        $html2pdf->Output('bookmark.pdf');
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
?>
```

### showimage.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("db");
$rs = mysql_query("select * from gallery");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$imagebytes = $row[imgdata];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $imagebytes;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old but since no correct answer was provided, I'll try to pinch in. Html2pdf is made to load image directly from disk not using http. In the current version, you would have received an error saying it can't load the image...

The usual way to link the image would be :

```
<img src='/path/to/image.png' alt="image" />
```

instead of:

```
<img src=showimage.php alt="image" />
```

In your case, if you don't want to write the image on disk, you could try embedding it as data-uri (I haven't test if html2pdf support this)

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row[imgdata]).'"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you get an error message. Maybe it is an idea to make PHP more verbose on error/warning reporting.

Please see [error_reporting@php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). There is also a default value set in your php.ini.

What might be an issue in your showimage.php:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$imagebytes = $row[imgdata];
```

mysql_fetch_assoc returns an associative array. Since *imgdata* is not even a variable in this case you should either change *imgdata* to *$imgdata* and init the variable with the column name of your MySQL table holding your image data/blob. **If** the column name **is** *imgdata*, you might just need to put it in quotation marks, like this:

```
$imagebytes = $row['imgdata'];
```

On third thought, I might miss here, that you are using *imgdata* as a constant (then you should consider making the constant identifier all uppercase for better readability) - if that is the case, make sure the constant holds the correct column name to your MySQL table.

Comment: "$imagebytes = $row['imgdata'];"... this not work.
Error message:
ERROR nÂ°6
File : html2pdf.class.php
Line : 1319

Impossible to load the image showimage.php.

When i load image from FTP, then work perfect.

Comment: I missed another thing: Your line `$rs = mysql_query("select * from gallery");` will definitely lead into problems if your MySQL table holds more than one entry. Meaning you have to add a conditional, that is `WHERE` clause, to narrow down the result to one single image. For example if your table has an `id` column try `$rs = mysql_query("select * from gallery where id = 1");`.